# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token case

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I am coming across a problem in my code. It's telling me I have an:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token case"

and I'm not entirely sure what that means. Any help would be greatly appreciated! The problem seems to start with this line of code.

```
{
   case UP:
      mowerPosition[mowerY][mowerX] = 0; 
      pattern[mowerY][mowerX] = 1; 
      mowerY--;
      if (mowerY >= 0) {
         mowerPosition[mowerY][mowerX] = 1; 
      } else {
         mowerY++;
         mowerPosition[mowerY][mowerX] = 1; 
      }
      break;
   case DOWN:
      mowerPosition[mowerY][mowerX] = 0; 
      pattern[mowerY][mowerX] = 1; 
      mowerY++;
      if (mowerY < COLUMNS) {
         mowerPosition[mowerY][mowerX] = 1; 
      } else {
         mowerY--;
         mowerPosition[mowerY][mowerX] = 1; 
      }
      break;
   case RIGHT:
      mowerPosition[mowerY][mowerX] = 0; 
      pattern[mowerY][mowerX] = 1; 
      mowerX++;
      if (mowerX < ROWS) {
         mowerPosition[mowerY][mowerX] = 1; 
      } else {
         mowerX--;
         mowerPosition[mowerY][mowerX] = 1;
      }
      break;
   case LEFT:
      mowerPosition[mowerY][mowerX] = 0; 
      pattern[mowerY][mowerX] = 1; 
      mowerX--;
      if (mowerX >= 0) {
         mowerPosition[mowerY][mowerX] = 1; 
      } else {
         mowerX++;
         mowerPosition[mowerY][mowerX] = 1;
      }
      break;
   }
```

Comment: Are those `UP`, `DOWN`, `LEFT` and `RIGHT` variables?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle producing your error? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Marco brings up a salient point-- if those aren't variables and are supposed to be strings, they need to be wrapped in quotes.  Incidentally, usually the dev tools will report the line and position of an error, so you can trap it down-- generally I think a syntax error means it sees some character (like a bracket, or a comma) where it wouldn't expect.

Comment: *I'm not entirely sure what that means* It means exactly what it says. It could hardly be clearer. It means that there was an unexpected token `case`. By the way, what were you hoping this code, and the `case` statements in it, were going to do?

Comment: I think you need to post more code, or a jsfiddle as @Marco suggested.  Usually `unexpected token case` would indicate that you'd missed a closing brace or something before a `case` keyword.

Comment: This code here shows the exact same error, even though I didn't declared the variables in case. I've just missed on purpose the first curly brace: https://jsfiddle.net/2jb3of9y/

Comment: Take a look at this link too http://www.prowebguru.com/2016/03/solution-to-unexpected-token-switch-javascript-error/#.V_1PO3p5E3k

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly use the switch- case like this, seems you are missing `switch`

```
switch(expression) {
    case n:
        code block
        break;
    case n:
        code block
        break;
    default:
        default code block
}
```

Comment: And if he is using `switch(expression)`, maybe he is using undefined variables like UP, DOWN, LEFT and RIGHT